# Proving that there exists a subsequence of $(q_n)^\infty_{n=1}$that converges to a certain $l$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $(q_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence which maps $\mathbb{N}$ onto $P=\{p \in \mathbb{Q} : 0\leq p \leq 1\}$. Show that if $l\in[0,1]$ then there exists a subsequence $(q_{n_j})^\infty_{j=1}$ which converges to $l$. My approach/start was like this:

As $(q_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ is bounded, there exist $b_0$ and $c_0$ with $b_0\lt c_0$ such that $q_n\in[b_0,c_0]$. In this case, $b_0=0$ and $c_0=1$. Let $l\in[0,1]$ be $\frac{b_0+c_0}{2}$, the midpoint of the closed interval. Because of surjectivity, there are infinitely many $n$ for which $q_n\in[b_0, l]$. Then, $A_1=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:q_n\in[b_1,c_1]\}$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Now this process can be iterated;

At the $j$th step we will have $[b_j,c_j]$ such that$[b_j,c_j] \subset[b_{j-1},c_{j-1}]$ and $c_j-b_j=\frac{c_0-b_0}{2^j}$. This gives $A_j=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:q_n\in[b_j,c_j]\}$. So, $b_j\leq q_{n_j} \leq c_j$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$. $(n_j)^\infty_{j=1}$ is a subsequence of $\mathbb{N}$ by the diagonal procedure. The sequence $(b_j)^\infty_{j=1}$ is inreasing and bounded above by $l$, so it converges to $l$ as $j\to\infty$. Since $c_j-=\frac{c_0-b_0}{2^j}+b_j$, $c_j$ converges to $l$ too, as $j\to\infty$. Since $b_j\leq q_{n_j} \leq c_j$, $b_j\to l$ as $l\to\infty$ so as $n\to\infty$ too. $\square$

I'm not sure if all the steps I take are valid, or if some things are just complete nonsense. Hopefully though, this is somewhat in the right direction.

Comment: That seems to go bad as soon as you say "Let $l$ be $\frac{b_0+c_0}2$". You can't decide for yourself what $l$ is going to be; the problem asks you to construct a proof where $l$ is _given_ to you.

Comment: Well then. There goes all my hard work. I'm really stuck on this proof, have you got any clue to head me in the right direction?

Comment: You might mean $c_1=\frac{b_0+c_0}{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Decide, for example, that you want $|q_{n_j}-l|<\frac1j$ for all $j$.

At step $j$, note that the interval $(l-\frac1j,l+\frac1j)$ contains infinitely many of the $q_n$s -- this interval may not lie completely within $[0,1]$, but it still overlaps enough to have many rationals in the intersection. Some of these rationals must be $q_n$ for some $n$ *larger than* $n_{j-1}$. Choose one of those as $n_j$ and continue with the next step.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but as of now I just don't see it... I think I might just continue on tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We have been given an arbitrary number $l\in[0,1]$. We know, from $\mathbb{Q}$'s density in $\mathbb{R}$ that there exists a sequence $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of rational numbers in $[0,1]$, such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=l$$
Now, the sequence given to us is dense in $[0,1]$ - since it consists of all the rational numbers in $[0,1]$. Remember that:

> A set $D\subseteq A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $A$ if and only if for every $x\in A$ and for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $y\in D$ such that:
>   $$|x-y|<\epsilon$$

Can you complete the rest, using some of the arguments you used in your first proof?

**Edit:** Due to $q_n$'s density in $[0,1]$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there are infinitely many terms of $(q_n)_n$ in $(p_k-\epsilon,p_k+\epsilon)$, for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. So, choosing $e_m=\frac{1}{m}$, we can construct (complete the rest of the argument) a subsequence of $(q_n)_n$ such that:
$$|q_{n_m}-p_m|<\frac{1}{m}$$
In this way, we can show (complete this part) that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}q_{n_m}=l$$
The general idea is to find terms of $(q_n)_n$ arbitrarily close to the terms of $p_n$ and thus, let $p_n$ "drag" $q_{n_m}$ close to $l$ - intuitively.

**Question:** Could you explain me the idea behind your proof, so as to fully understand you arguments? I' ve been lost as far as $l=\frac{b_0+c_0}{2}$ is concerned.

Comment: could you maybe elaborate? As of now, I haven't found the connection between my arguments and what you're telling me here. I'm also not sure which of my arguments are useful, as someone already pointed out most of it is based on the fact I chose $l$ to be $\frac{b_0+c_0}{2}$...